# Js/Jq разница между $(this) и this

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте,  подскажите в чем разница между передачей элемента в on click:

```
<div onclick="foo(this);">
```

И

```
<div onclick="foo($(this));">
```

Comment: `onclick="console.log(this);console.log($(this))"`

Comment: это как разница между передачей `'qwerty'` и `'not  querty'`, разные обьекты передаются

Answer (score 6):

`this` сожержит элемент, на котором произошел click. Т.е. непосредственно элемент. А `$(this)` - это уже объект jQuery, который содержит тот элемент, на который кликнули. Если на пальцах, то `this` - конфета без фантика, а `$(this)` - это коробка с одной конфетой.